# PhoneGap inline html5 video black flash before video starts

Tags: cordova, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video that flashes black only when compiled through phonegap. When the video starts, there's a black flash between the poster and the first frame of the video. The flash lasts between 0.5 seconds and 5 seconds. When I take the exact same page and just run it in a browser instead of phonegap, it plays seamlessly from the poster to the video.

If I play the video once and come back to it, there is no flash, it's only the first time. I've tested this while waiting for a sufficient amount of time for the videos to be loaded completely, so it's not that they aren't loaded all the way yet.

I can think of a few hacks to fix this, but I'm hoping there is a clean solution to this.

Javascript:

```
onVideoExit()
videoElement.currentTime = 0;
videoElement.pause();

onVideoEnter()
videoElement.play();
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <video  width="140" height="210" webkit-playsinline preload>
        <source src=http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</div>
```

config.xml:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

Comment: a side note, the 'preload' attribute has no affect on this, it just takes longer for the video to turn off the poster, but the black flash is the same length

Comment: waiting for the loadeddata event also doesn't help. the flash happens even if I wait for 5 minutes before playing the video. The first time I play the video since refreshing the view, it flashes black. (it doesn't flash black if the video is tiny or if I'm on fast internet). I think the IOS webview library isn't handling the loaded events correctly. The video takes time to switch from the poster image to the video

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an event listener to know when the video is properly loaded.

```
var theVideo = document.getElementById("myAwesomeVideo");
theVideo.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    theVideo.play();
});
```

Comment: forgot to mention, I tried that. It's only in phonegap. Mobile safari handles it fine. I can have the preload attribute set or wait for the loadeddata event. regardless, it flashes black before playing inline for an amount of time that seems to be dependent on bandwidth and video size